# Unix 'calendar' program upgraded to work with multiple years?

Tags: calendar

Many years ago, there was a Unix 'calendar' program. Every user would 
create their own ~/.calendar file and root would run 'calendar' once 
daily to send people email reminders from their ~/.calendar files.

For identification, the first part of "man calendar" shows:

```
NAME 
     calendar - reminder service 

SYNOPSIS 
     calendar [-ab] [-A num] [-B num] [-f calendarfile] [-t [[[cc]yy][mm]]dd] 

DESCRIPTION 
     The calendar utility checks the current directory or the directory speci- 
     fied by the CALENDAR_DIR environment variable for a file named calendar 
     and displays lines that begin with either today’s date or tomorrow’s.  On 
     Fridays, events on Friday through Monday are displayed.
```

The problem: this program only lets you specify a month and day in the 
~/.calendar file, and will alert you every year on that month and day.

I want to alert myself to renew my driver's license Sep 13 2019 (one 
month before it expires). However, if I add "Sep 13" to my ~/.calendar 
file, it will remind me every Sep 13, not just Sep 13 2019.

I realize there are many workarounds + newer programs that do 
something similar, but has the calendar program itself ever been 
upgraded to do this?

Comment: How about `Dec 31 - revise .calendar file for next year`? Alternately, you could do something like `calendar -f .calendar-\`date +%Y\`` in your profile

Answer (score 0):

Calendar works only with day and months
on both BSD and systemV version.
There are some possible worksaround
for example using at

```
at 2:44pm Jul 15 ,2016

at> echo  "remind this"|mail -s reminder user
```

Or better use [remind](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3529?page=0,1)